# NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.sendEvent

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm running into a problem with a combination of Spring 3.1.1 and Apache CXF 2.7.10.  I'm guessing I'm just missing a dependency but can't for the life of me figure out what.

When starting my service I get the following exception:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.sendEvent(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/factory/FactoryBeanListener$Event;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:540)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:135)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:977)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:509)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'serviceBeans' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServiceFactoryBean.sendEvent(Lorg/apache/cxf/service/factory/FactoryBeanListener$Event;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 35 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

build.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="IngestionService" default="help" basedir=".">

    <property file="my-local.ant.properties"/>
    <property file="local.ant.properties"/>

<!--    <property name="service.properties.file" value="contentService.windows.properties" /> -->
    <property name="service.properties.file" value="contentService.properties" />

    <path id="javadoc.path">
        <pathelement path="${BuildSrc}"/>
        <pathelement path="${BuildSrc}/../generated"/>
    </path>

    <path id="javadoc.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="apache_activemq/activemq-all-5.1.0.jar" />
            <include name="apache_activemq/commons-pool-1.4.jar" />
            <include name="apache_activemq/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_commons_coll/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_commons_io/commons-io-1.4.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/commons-lang-2.1.jar" />

            <include name="apache_cxf/asm-3.3.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/commons-codec-1.9.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />

            <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-2.0.3-incubator.jar" />
            <!--<include name="apache_cxf/cxf-api-2.7.10.jar" />-->
            <!--<include name="apache_cxf/cxf-bundle-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />-->
            <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-core-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wss10-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wss11-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wssc-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wsu10-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-policy-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-common-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/xalan-2.7.0.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/xml-resolver-1.2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar" />
            <include name="apache_cxf/xmlsec-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
            <include name="apache_ibatis/ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar" />
            <include name="apache_ibatis/org.apache.commons.dbcp.jar" />
            <include name="aspectj/aspectjrt-1.5.2a.jar" />
            <include name="aspectj/aspectjweaver-1.5.2a.jar" />
            <include name="jackson/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar" />
            <include name="jackson/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar" />
            <include name="jackson/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar" />
            <include name="javax/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar" />
            <include name="javax/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar" />
            <include name="javax/jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar" />
            <include name="jaxb/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar" />
            <include name="jaxb/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar" />

            <include name="jetty/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
            <include name="jetty/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
            <include name="jetty/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
            <include name="jetty/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
            <include name="jetty/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
            <include name="jetty/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />

            <include name="log4j/log4j-1.2.13.jar" />
            <include name="log4j/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar" />

            <include name="oracle_jdbc/ojdbc14.jar" />

            <include name="other/antlr-2.7.7.jar" />
            <include name="other/commons-codec-1.9.jar" />
            <include name="other/commons-lang-2.6.jar" />
            <include name="other/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
            <include name="other/ehcache-2.7.4.jar" />
            <include name="other/httpasyncclient-4.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/httpclient-4.3.2.jar" />
            <include name="other/httpcore-4.3.1.jar" />
            <include name="other/httpcore-nio-4.3.1.jar" />
            <include name="other/jasypt-1.9.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/joda-time-2.2.jar" />
            <include name="other/js-1.7R2.jar" />
            <include name="other/mina-core-2.0.7.jar" />
            <include name="other/oauth-20100527.jar" />
            <include name="other/oauth-provider-20100527.jar" />
            <include name="other/opensaml-2.6.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/openws-1.5.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/serializer-2.7.1.jar" />
            <include name="other/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar" />
            <include name="other/velocity-1.7.jar" />
            <include name="other/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" />
            <include name="other/xml-resolver-1.2.jar" />
            <include name="other/xmltooling-1.4.0.jar" />

            <include name="quartz/quartz-all-1.6.0.jar" />
            <include name="spring/aopalliance-1.0.jar" />

            <include name="spring/spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <!--<include name="spring/spring-asm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar" />-->
            <include name="spring/spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-context-support-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-expression-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-ibatis-2.0.8.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-tx-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
            <include name="spring/spring-webmvc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />

            <include name="xerces/xercesImpl.jar" />

        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!--
        Official Build Target
    -->
    <target name="buildtool" depends="local.validate">
        <ant antfile="${BuildImport}/import.ant.xml" target="import.initialize" />


        <path id="compile.classpath">
            <fileset dir="${lib}">
                <include name="apache_activemq/activemq-all-5.1.0.jar" />
                <include name="apache_activemq/commons-pool-1.4.jar" />
                <include name="apache_activemq/geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec-1.0.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_commons_coll/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_commons_io/commons-io-1.4.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/commons-lang-2.1.jar" />

                <include name="apache_cxf/asm-3.3.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/commons-codec-1.9.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />

                <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-2.0.3-incubator.jar" />
                <!--<include name="apache_cxf/cxf-api-2.7.10.jar" />-->
                <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-bundle-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-core-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0-milestone2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wss10-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wss11-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wssc-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-bindings-wsu10-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-policy-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-common-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/xalan-2.7.0.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/xml-resolver-1.2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/XmlSchema-1.3.2.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/xmlschema-core-2.1.0.jar" />
                <include name="apache_cxf/xmlsec-2.0.0-rc1.jar" />
                <include name="apache_ibatis/ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar" />
                <include name="apache_ibatis/org.apache.commons.dbcp.jar" />
                <include name="aspectj/aspectjrt-1.5.2a.jar" />
                <include name="aspectj/aspectjweaver-1.5.2a.jar" />
                <include name="jackson/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar" />
                <include name="jackson/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar" />
                <include name="jackson/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar" />
                <include name="javax/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar" />
                <include name="javax/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar" />
                <include name="javax/jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar" />
                <include name="jaxb/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar" />
                <include name="jaxb/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar" />

                <include name="jetty/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
                <include name="jetty/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
                <include name="jetty/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
                <include name="jetty/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
                <include name="jetty/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />
                <include name="jetty/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar" />

                <include name="log4j/log4j-1.2.13.jar" />
                <include name="log4j/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar" />

                <include name="oracle_jdbc/ojdbc14.jar" />

                <include name="other/antlr-2.7.7.jar" />
                <include name="other/commons-codec-1.9.jar" />
                <include name="other/commons-lang-2.6.jar" />
                <include name="other/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" />
                <include name="other/ehcache-2.7.4.jar" />
                <include name="other/httpasyncclient-4.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/httpclient-4.3.2.jar" />
                <include name="other/httpcore-4.3.1.jar" />
                <include name="other/httpcore-nio-4.3.1.jar" />
                <include name="other/jasypt-1.9.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/joda-time-2.2.jar" />
                <include name="other/js-1.7R2.jar" />
                <include name="other/mina-core-2.0.7.jar" />
                <include name="other/oauth-20100527.jar" />
                <include name="other/oauth-provider-20100527.jar" />
                <include name="other/opensaml-2.6.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/openws-1.5.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/serializer-2.7.1.jar" />
                <include name="other/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar" />
                <include name="other/velocity-1.7.jar" />
                <include name="other/woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" />
                <include name="other/xml-resolver-1.2.jar" />
                <include name="other/xmltooling-1.4.0.jar" />

                <include name="quartz/quartz-all-1.6.0.jar" />
                <include name="spring/aopalliance-1.0.jar" />

                <include name="spring/spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <!--<include name="spring/spring-asm-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar" />-->
                <include name="spring/spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-context-support-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-expression-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-ibatis-2.0.8.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-tx-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />
                <include name="spring/spring-webmvc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar" />

                <include name="xerces/xercesImpl.jar" />

            </fileset>
        </path>
 ...     
           <!-- compile sources -->
        <javac destdir="${BuildMeta}/classes" 
               debug="on"
               optimize="on"
               deprecation="on"
               target="1.6" source="1.6">
            <src path="${BuildSrc}" />
            <src path="${BuildSrc}/../generated" />
            <classpath>
                <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <!-- compile test classes -->
        <javac destdir="${BuildMeta}/classes_test" 
               debug="on"
               optimize="on"
               deprecation="on"
               target="1.6" source="1.6">
            <src path="${BuildSrc}/../test"/>
            <!-- skip standalone test classes -->
            <exclude name="standalone/**"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
                <path refid="compile.test.classpath" />
                <pathelement location="${BuildMeta}/classes"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <mkdir dir="${BuildMeta}/integration"/>
        <!-- compile integration classes -->
        <javac destdir="${BuildMeta}/integration"
                debug="on"
                optimize="on"
                deprecation="on"
                target="1.6" source="1.6">
            <src path="${BuildSrc}/../integration/src"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
                <path refid="compile.test.classpath" />
                <pathelement location="${BuildMeta}/classes"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <!-- Copy Resources to classes directory for unit test and to be included in WAR file -->
```

...

```
        <!-- Create war -->
        <jar destfile="${BuildDist}/ingestion.war" basedir="${BuildMeta}/intermediate/"/>
        <jar destfile="${BuildDist}/ingestion_integration_tests.jar" basedir="${BuildMeta}/integration/"/>        

        <!-- Create Config tar -->
        <tar destfile="${BuildDist}/${BuildName}-config.tar">
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../config">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../lib/log4j">
                <include name="log4j-1.2.13.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../lib/slf4j">
                <include name="slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar" />
                <include name="slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../lib/oracle_jdbc">
                <include name="ojdbc14.jar" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../install">
                <include name="install.xml" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../resources/jetty">
                <include name="webdefault.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </tar>

        <tar destfile="${BuildDist}/integrationIngestionFiles.tar">
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../integration/feeds">
                <include name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        </tar>

        <!-- run unit tests if property is set to true -->
        <condition property="SkipTests">
            <not>
                <equals arg1="true" arg2="${BuildTest}" casesensitive="false" trim="true"/>
            </not>
        </condition>

        <antcall target="testtool" />
    </target>    
...    

    <!--
        Start a local intance of Jetty, build and deploy the war.
    -->
    <target name="local.deploy" depends="local.validate">
        <property name="jetty.folder" value="jetty-8"/>
        <property name="jetty.dir" value="${BuildSrc}/../../tools/${jetty.folder}" />

        <!-- verify jetty is there -->

        <available file="${jetty.dir}" type="dir" property="jetty.present"/>        
        <fail unless="jetty.present" message="Unable to locate the jetty instance at ${jetty.dir}"/>

        <antcall target="buildtool"/>
        <delete file="${jetty.dir}/webapps/ingestion.war"/>
        <copy file="${BuildDist}/ingestion.war" todir="${jetty.dir}/webapps" />
        <!-- datasource configuration -->
        <copy file="${BuildSrc}/../lib/oracle_jdbc/ojdbc14.jar" todir="${jetty.dir}/lib" />
        <copy file="${BuildSrc}/../config/dev/jetty-datasource.xml" todir="${jetty.dir}/etc" overwrite="true"/>
        <!-- logging configuration -->
        <copy file="${BuildSrc}/../lib/slf4j/slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar" todir="${jetty.dir}/lib" />
        <copy file="${BuildSrc}/../lib/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar" todir="${jetty.dir}/lib" />
        <copy file="${BuildSrc}/../lib/log4j/log4j-1.2.13.jar" todir="${jetty.dir}/lib" />
        <copy overwrite="true"  file="${BuildSrc}/../config/log4j.xml" todir="${jetty.dir}/resources" />
        <copy overwrite="true" todir="${jetty.dir}/resources/transform" >
            <fileset dir="${BuildSrc}/../resources/transform" includes="**"/>
        </copy>
        <!-- external environmental server property configuration -->
        <copy overwrite="true" file="${BuildSrc}/../config/${service.properties.file}" tofile="${jetty.dir}/resources/contentService.properties" />

        <!-- start jetty -->
        <antcall target="local.run"/>
    </target>

    <!--
        Start a local intance of Jetty
    -->
    <target name="local.run" depends="local.validate" unless="local.run.no">
        <property name="jetty.folder" value="jetty-8"/>
        <property name="jetty.dir" value="${BuildSrc}/../../tools/${jetty.folder}" />

        <!-- Set this propery to -ea to enable asserts -->
        <property name="java.assert" value="-da" />

        <!-- Set to "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote" to be able to connect to jvm using jconsole -->
        <property name="java.use_jmx" value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"/>

        <!-- Set to "-agentlib:hprof=heap=all,format=b" to profile java heap -->
        <!-- You must stop the java instance (see local.stop) rather than kill it as the profile info is written on exit -->
        <!-- see <jetty home>/java.hprof or java.hprof.txt for profile info -->
        <property name="java.heapprofile" value=""/>

        <!-- Set to "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" to have profile dumped when first OutOfMemoryError is thrown -->
        <property name="java.memorydump" value=""/>

        <!-- Set to "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000" to allow attach of debugger -->
        <property name="java.debug" value=""/>

        <available file="${jetty.dir}" type="dir" property="jetty.present"/>        
        <fail unless="jetty.present" message="Unable to locate the jetty instance at ${jetty.dir}"/>

        <!-- start jetty -->
        <java dir="${jetty.dir}"
              jar="${jetty.dir}/start.jar"
              fork="true"
              failonerror="true"
              maxmemory="128m" >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${jetty.dir}/start.jar"/>
                <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
            </classpath>

            <jvmarg value="-Djetty.port=8080"/>
            <jvmarg value="-DSTOP.KEY=cdv"/>
            <jvmarg value="-DSTOP.PORT=8079"/>

            <!-- See above properties for descriptions -->
            <jvmarg value="${java.assert}"/>
            <jvmarg value="${java.use_jmx}"/>

            <!-- Args to allow for remote debugging -->
            <jvmarg value="-Xdebug" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8585,server=y,suspend=n" />

<!-- 
    Empty properties causes Unix Main class not found error in java, leave these commented out unless used.
            <jvmarg value="${java.heapprofile}"/>
            <jvmarg value="${java.memorydump}"/>
            <jvmarg value="${java.debug}"/>
-->
            <arg line="etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-plus.xml etc/jetty-datasource.xml" /> 
        </java>
    </target>


    ...

</project>
```

Comment: Not really that you're missing a dependency; it's more like you have a different version of a library than a dependent library is expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be really helpful if you added a link to your `pom.xml` or `build.xml` or whatever dependency management you use.

- You list `cxf-2.0.3-incubator.jar` which looks odd to me.
- `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.10.jar` DOES have a `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean` class with a `sendEvent(FactoryBeanListener.Event ev, Object ... args)` method

-> you have different versions of the `AbstractServiceFactoryBean` class in your classpath

Comment: After doing some research, I've discovered that its probably jetty 6 which is causing the problem.  I tried making a basic starter cxf-rs war which runs in tomcat, but I get the same exception when trying to run it in jetty 6.  I'm going to try to upgrade jetty to see if this fixes my original issue, as I am working in a rather complex project.

Comment: Upgrading jetty did not work.  I upgraded to Jetty 8, which resulted in getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like I was able to finally solve it by removing cxf-bundle-3.0.0-milestone2.jar and adding apache_cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.0-milestone2.jar, apache_cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.0-milestone2.jar andapache_cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.0-milestone2.jar.  I also had to remove the Log4J reference as it conflicted with slf4j.

Comment: my2cents for you: let Maven handle the dependencies mess for you rather than doing it manually with Ant.

Comment: Over time I hope do to that.  I'm currently dealing with a legacy codebase.